# Reorder factor levels that are dates but only month and year in R

Tags: r, date, ggvis

I'm using `ggvis` stacked barplots to create a graph where the x-axis is a time series of dates and the y-axis are frequencies.

The dates however, are in the format "Apr 2015" i.e. months and years.

In `ggvis`, this means that I have to make the dates in my dataframe factors.

I'm having trouble converting these month-year dates into factors that are ordered by their date. Instead, I get this order
"Apr 2015, Jun 2015, May 2015"

This is my code:

```
selecteddates <- with(dailyIndMelt, dailyIndMelt[date >= as.Date(input$monthlydateInd[1]) & date <= as.Date(input$monthlydateInd[2]),])
selecteddates <- aggregate(selecteddates[,3],by=list(selecteddates$variable,substr(selecteddates$date,1,7)),sum)
colnames(selecteddates) <- c("industry", "date", "vacancyno")
selecteddates$date <- as.Date(paste(selecteddates$date,"-28",sep=""))
selecteddates <- selecteddates[order(as.Date(selecteddates$date)),]
selecteddates$date <- format(selecteddates$date, "%m %Y")
selecteddates$date <- factor(selecteddates$date)
levels(selecteddates$date) <- levels(selecteddates$date)[order(as.Date(levels(selecteddates$date), format="%m %Y"))]
levels(selecteddates)
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the levels in the order you want, you can feed the desired order to the `levels` argument of `factor`. For example:

```
selecteddates$date <- factor(selecteddates$date, 
                             levels=paste(month.abb, rep(2014:2015, each=12)))
```

`month.abb` is a built-in vector of month abbreviations. The `paste` function pastes together the month abbreviations and the year values, so you get the correct ordering. I used years 2014 and 2015 for illustration. Just change that to whatever years appear in your data.

Here's the `paste` statement on its own for illustration:

```
paste(month.abb, rep(2014:2015, each=12))

 [1] "Jan 2014" "Feb 2014" "Mar 2014" "Apr 2014" "May 2014" "Jun 2014" "Jul 2014" "Aug 2014"
 [9] "Sep 2014" "Oct 2014" "Nov 2014" "Dec 2014" "Jan 2015" "Feb 2015" "Mar 2015" "Apr 2015"
[17] "May 2015" "Jun 2015" "Jul 2015" "Aug 2015" "Sep 2015" "Oct 2015" "Nov 2015" "Dec 2015"
```

Ideally, you can get the desired years programmatically, directly from your data. If your dates start out in a date format, you can do something analogous to this:

```
library(lubridate) # For year function

# Fake date data
dates = seq(as.Date("2010-01-15"), as.Date("2015-01-15"), by="1 day")

# Extract the years from the dates and use them to create the month-year levels
levels = paste(month.abb, rep(sort(unique(year(dates))), each=12))
```

In the code above, the `sort` ensures the years are in order, even if the dates are out of order.